# How to make vector field plot from NDSolveValue Solution?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, vector

I am solving Laplace equation on circular domain from which i get solution for potential.
**The code I used:**

```
w = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}]
op = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]
h = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 50, x^2 + y^2 == 4 && x > 1.99], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == -50, x^2 + y^2 == 4 && x < -1.99]};
uif = NDSolveValue[{op == 
    NeumannValue[0, x^2 + y^2 == 4 && -1.9 < x < 1.9], h}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] w]
ContourPlot[uif[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] w, 
 ColorFunction -> "Temperature", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Contours -> 30]
```

[image: Solution]

Now i would like to calculate **current density** (gradient of potential) from solution for potential and plot it as **vector field** on the same graph. **Can this be done with some built in function or how would i go about this?**

Comment: Your graphic doesn't correspond to the code.

Comment: @andre Thanks. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `StreamPlot` and combine plots with `Show`.

```
contour = ContourPlot[uif[x, y], {x, y} ∈ w, ColorFunction -> "Temperature", Contours -> 20];
stream = StreamPlot[ Evaluate@Grad[uif[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ w];

Show[contour, stream]
```

[image: streamPlot]

Comment: That' s what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
VectorPlot[Evaluate[Grad[uif[x, y], {x, y}]], 
 Element[{x, y}, uif["ElementMesh"]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`StreamDensityPlot` does all what you need :

```
field=Grad[uif[x, y],{x,y}];
StreamDensityPlot[field, {x, y} \[Element] w,
  Mesh->{{{20,Directive[Thick,Dashed]},18,16,14,12,{10,Thick}}},
  MeshStyle->Black,
  StreamStyle-> Black,
  ColorFunctionScaling->False,
  ColorFunction-> (Hue[#5/100.]&)
  ]
```

[image]

I have interpreted the "current density" in your question as the *module* of the gradient of the potential (= the module of the field, that is to say a scalar, not a vector). That's the reason why I have added the iso-current-density curves (the black curves) in the graphic.

**EDIT**

A version with a legend :

```
field=Grad[uif[x, y],{x,y}];
StreamDensityPlot[field, {x, y} \[Element] w,
  Mesh->{{{20,Directive[Thick,Dashed]},18,16,14,12,{10,Thick}}},
  MeshStyle->Black,
  PlotLegends->Automatic,
  StreamStyle-> Black,
  RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,vx,vy,n},n<70],
  ColorFunction-> Hue
  ]
```

[image]